# Does 'primary key' & 'foreign key' concept exist/required in Berkeley DB?

Tags: sql, berkeley-db

As per this [link](http://doc.gnu-darwin.org/am/second.html)

A table is created with primary key(`student_id`) in SQL  as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE students(student_id CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    lastname CHAR(15), firstname CHAR(15), PRIMARY KEY(student_id));
```

In Berkeley DB, We could do this, using following code:

```
struct student_record {
    char student_id[4];
    char last_name[15];
    char first_name[15];
};

DB *dbp, *sdbp;
int ret;

/* Open/create primary */
if ((ret = db_create(&dbp, dbenv, 0)) != 0)
    handle_error();
if ((ret = dbp->open(dbp,
    "students.db", NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0600)) != 0)
    handle_error();
```

From the application's perspective, putting things into the database works exactly as it does without a secondary index; one can simply insert records into the primary database. In SQL one would do the following:

```
INSERT INTO student
    VALUES ("WC42", "Churchill      ", "Winston        ");
```

and in Berkeley DB, one does:

```
struct student_record s;
DBT data, key;

memset(&key, 0, sizeof(DBT));
memset(&data, 0, sizeof(DBT));
memset(&s, 0, sizeof(struct student_record));
key.data = "WC42";
key.size = 4;
memcpy(&s.student_id, "WC42", sizeof(s.student_id));
memcpy(&s.last_name, "Churchill      ", sizeof(s.last_name));
memcpy(&s.first_name, "Winston        ", sizeof(s.first_name));
data.data = &s;
data.size = sizeof(s);
if ((ret = dbp->put(dbp, txn, &key, &data, 0)) != 0)
    handle_error(ret);
```

My question:

Are we setting the primary key(`student_id`) when we call `db_create()`? If no, How the rows be unique based on `student_id` field?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: What is "C / C++"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the *whole* page, not just the first few lines of it.

The way keys are set is explored further down. It has nothing to do with `db_create()`, which doesn't even define any "table" structure; indeed, as you said yourself in the Lounge, Berkeley DBs are non-relational and have no such concept. Instead, keys are set "manually", per-row. You may base the keys on Student ID if you wish, but it won't happen automatically.

Comment: yes, you are right!  `key.data = "WC42";dbp->put(dbp, txn, &key, &data, 0)`

Comment: But, How do we make sure the foreign key constraint be enabled in berkeley DB?